# How to select automatically a text input?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom-events

I want a text input selected (as if I had clicked on) when I click on another element on the page. I can't figure out how to do it?

Comment: Which element you click and which element you want `focus` on? Add some code, otherwise this question will probably get closed.

Comment: I click an an image and I focus on an input

Comment: Add the code with the image and the input, and if you already tried something - add it also.

Comment: I have my answer, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this: `pure js way`

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" 
onclick="document.getElementById('target').focus(); return false;">

<input type ="text" id="target"/>
```

Clicking on image will set focus on the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input field has id `#input` then solution would be

```
// Wrapper function needed to ensure that DOM elements have been already rendered.
(function() {

  $( '#input' ).focus(); // jQuery

  document.getElementByID( 'input' ).focus(); // VanillaJS

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have not tried it though. It's worth noting that it is based on jquery.

```
//set focus by default
$("your_input").focus();
//if the focus is lost set it again
$("div").focusout(function(){
    $("your_input").focus();
});
```